# Question About Locally Principal Divisors in Shafarevich

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In his "Basic Algebraic Geometry(Volume 1)", on page 151, Shafarevich says:

> Suppose that the variety $ X $ is nonsingular. In this case, for any prime divisor $ C \subset X $ and any point $ x \in X $ there exists an open set $ U \ni x $ in which $ C $ is defined in $ U $ by a local equation $ \pi. $

I accept this.

> If $ D = \sum_{i} k_{i}C_{i} $ is any divisor, and each of the $ C_{i} $ is defined in $ U $ by a local equation $ \pi_{i}, $ then we have $ D = \text{div}(f) $ in $ U, $ where $ f = \prod_{i} \pi_{i}^{k_{i}}. $

Why is $ D = \text{div}(f), $ with $ f $ as defined? I know that the Weil divisor $ D $ is locally principal, but I wish I could have an explanation for this section that doesn't assume prior knowledge of that.

> Thus every point $ x $ has a neighbourhood in which $ D $ is principal. From among all such neighbourhoods, we can choose a finite cover $ X = \bigcup U_{i}, $ and $ D = \text{div}(f_{i}) $ on $ U_{i}. $

Why can we choose such a cover?

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathrm{div}(f)$ for a regular function $f$? This might help responders (or you) resolve your confusion about your question.

Comment: $ \text{div}(f) = \sum_{i} v_{Y_{i}}(f)Y_{i}, $ where the sum ranges over all prime divisors of $ X, $ and $ f \in K(X)^{*}. $ Also, $ v_{Y} $ is the valuation of $ Y $ where $ K(X) $ is the fraction field of the DVR $ \mathcal{O}_{X,\eta} $ for a non-singular generic point $ \eta. $

Comment: Then this should be a straightforwards definition check. Do you see what to do by letting the $C_i$ be the prime divisors corresponding to the  $\pi_i$? You should be able to check that if $\pi_i$ is a defining equation for a prime divisor, then everything works just like the text says. For the open cover, most authors assume that their varieties have some nice finiteness assumption which implies that they're quasicompact - this is the property that any open cover has a finite subcover.